# Delimiting a string and dynamically creating objects

Tags: c#, string, object, dynamic

I wonder if you can help me with a program I’m trying to write.

I’m trying to parse a delimited file that uses apostrophes, ‘+’ and ‘:’ to delimit the information.   It’s hierarchical so that the apostrophes contain a cluster of information, within which information is delimited by the ‘+’ and then the ‘:’.

I’m parsing the text using Split and Substring, foreach’ing with foreach loops through string arrays in order to break down the information.   I’ve created a class that objects will be instantiated of and held in a list in order to contain the information for regurgitating or writing to a file later.

The thing that I’m stuck on is being able to iteratively create the objects dependent on what information I’ve parsed.  I want to be able to create an object, then change the properties of the class depending on what part of the string I’ve parsed.

What method is best to conditionally create objects and change properties on the fly?  Do I simply use a case/switch to break out the information and hardcode the updates?  It seems like there should be a better approach than this.

I'm also wondering if I should be letting the EMessage class do the work parsing strings etc., or simply use it as a container for information?  Is that a question of preference?

Many thanks.

Here's the main part.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            char[] segmentDelimiter = { '\'' };
            char[] elementDelimiter = { '=' };
            char[] subElementDelimiter = { '+' };
            char[] subElementFieldDelimiter = { ':' };
            string segmentDescription;
            List<EMessage> eMessages = new List<EMessage>();



            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\File.dat"))
            {
                string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string[] Segments = text.Split(segmentDelimiter);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} segments found \r\n", Segments.Length);
                EMessage eMessage = new EMessage();

                    foreach (string s in Segments)      // delimiting the Segments
                    {
                        string switchSegment = s.Substring(0, 3);
                        switch (switchSegment)
                        {
                            case "PLH":
                                //ediMessage.
                                Console.WriteLine("We've found the Header");
                                string[] Elements = s.Substring(4).Split(subElementDelimiter);
                                foreach (string e in Elements)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("E is: " + e);

                                }
                                break;
                            case "MHD":
                                Console.WriteLine("We've found MHD");
                                Console.WriteLine("The rest of the string is: " + s.Substring(4));
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Didn't work.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the class I'm trying to create and populate on the fly:

```
public class EDIMessage
{
    public int polNumber { get; set; }
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public PaymentDetails paymentDetails { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Vehicle vehicle { get; set; }




    public EMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New EMessage Object Created");
        Header = new Header();
        paymentDetails = new PaymentDetails();
        policyLocation = new PolLocation();
        vehicle = new Vehicle();

    }

}

public class Header
{
    public DateTime effStartDateTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime effEndDateTime {get; set;}
}

public class PaymentDetails
{
    public double Premium {get; set;}
}

public class Location
{
    public string AddressLine1 {get; set;}
    public string AddressLine2 {get; set;}
    public string AddressLine3 {get; set;}
    public string AddressLine4 {get; set;}
    public string AddressLine5 {get; set;}
    public string AddressLine6 {get; set;}
    public string PostCode {get; set;}
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public DateTime DateFirst {get; set;}
    public string vehicleCode { get; set; }
}
```

Data is here:

```
HED=1+CODE01:1'
BIB=A12345:1
+:England'
DAT=01:AN1:JAN01:01012001:01012001'
SHV=1'
FRD=12345678
+ANA:01:PPV:03
+HY
+01012017:150000
+31122017:120000
+2001-2001
+JANUARY 2000
+
+PCT
+.'

VEH=01012000
+123456:MAKE MODEL VEHICLE
+A
+B
+C
+01
+02
+
+01234
+0
+56789
+ELECTRIC
+
+
+1
+1'
```

Comment: Having an example of the data would be useful here.

Comment: Hi PaulF - added.

Comment: Are you sure the data is correct - there appear to be big sections with no starting apostrophe delimiter (line +.'  and final line +1' & no occurrences of the "PLH" or "MHD" strings to match your code.